# Node assigned to IOBANK

Tags: fpga, verilog, intel-fpga

I'm working with an Altera FPGA. In the Pin Planner there is a choice in the combo box for a 1-bit inout node to be connected to an "IOBANK_n" (under "Location" row). I was expecting only "PIN_nn" are available.

What does it mean to connect a 1-bit node to an IOBANK? or, if it's nonsense, then what type of objects do you connect to IOBANKs?

Answer (score 1):

The pins are grouped into I/O banks, each pin is part of one. The configuration of the I/O bank limits your freedom in the configuration of individual pins, as all the pins in the same bank share the same VCCIO (and possibly VREF).

In other words, if you want to configure an I/O pin to a certain standard and the Pin Planner doesn't let you, it could be because the configuration of the associated I/O bank makes the pin configuration you want impossible.